# Missing IIB Broker Directories

Tags: linux, ibm-integration-bus

/var/mqsi/components/*broker_name* is the default directory that the broker called *broker_name* stores its configuration information, as far as I am aware. Below this directory are the pid directories containing execution group information, stdout/stderr, as well as other things.

I don't know if it's relevant to the issue we're seeing, but for historic reasons we have this directory in a different location for our brokers: (/var/*broker_name*/data/mqsi/components/*broker_name*).

We are using IIB 9.0.0.7, and multi-instancing (so all the directories are on the same HNAS with different mounts). We have eight brokers, so /var/*broker_name_1*, /var/*broker_name_2*, etc. are each mount points; with directories /data/mqsi/components/*broker_name_n* below that.

Yesterday afternoon, the directory /var/*broker_name_n*/data/mqsi/components/*broker_name_n* disappeared from the file system for two of the brokers. The directory /var/*broker_name_n*/data/mqsi/components still exists; but the broker_name_n directory below components disappeared.

Because the processes are running in memory, the broker and applications on the execution groups carried on working until we restarted one of the brokers; at which point all of the execution groups disappeared. The other broker was still running, so I looked and saw that the directory was missing. restarting the broker recreated it, but not the execution groups.

Is this behaviour something that anyone has seen before? Could this be caused by something in IIB; or is it likely to be something on the system that caused this to happen? It's weird that it was that specific directory on both of the servers, if it's a file-system issue.

in /var/log/messages, we don't see any issues; except for errors because different processes can't find the files they need - e.g. BIP3108S: Unable to initialize the listener environment. Exception text getListenerParametersFromFile: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/*broker_name_1*/data/mqsi/components/*broker_name_1*/config/wsplugin6.conf (No such file or directory)

Is there any way to recover from this in IIB without reinstalling everything?

Comment: I'm not sure what caused your problem but for future reference check out "[mqsibackupbroker command - IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bn43000_.htm)" with a backup created you should be able to restore.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc, that answers the "Is there any way to recover from this" part very nicely

Comment: I checked the IIB 9 fixlist and do not see any existing APARs that match anything like what you experienced.  Is it possible someone removed them in error or there was a storage problem?

Comment: Storage problem is a possibility I suppose. No one removed them

Comment: Hello, your question is really specific and should be sent to IBM Support (via Service Request). Otherwise, from my point of view, there was an issue on your side and someone removed the files, there is no other way (or your disks are dead, but it's apparently not the case). I've experienced many weird behaviour, for exemple sometime the delete of and execution group doesn't delete the files on the server, and when you recreate an execution group with the same name the applications reappear without being deployed. But the other way, I've never witnessed this